# TypeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object is not iterable

Tags: scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to use OneHotEncoding on the categorical variables of the following dataset.
[image]

First, I'm trying to convert the 'Geography' column.
Here's what I've done so far:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer 

ct = ColumnTransformer(['Geography',OneHotEncoder(categories='auto'),[1]],remainder='passthrough')
df_ = ct.fit_transform(df.values)
```

However, when I try this, I get the following error: [image: error message]

Can someone help me to understand why this error occurs and how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the input parameter to the [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html). It expects a list of tuples.

### transformers : list of tuples

> List of (name, transformer, columns) tuples specifying the transformer objects to be applied to subsets of the data.

Try fixing it by converting the encoder params to a tuple

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([('Geography',OneHotEncoder(categories='auto'),[1])],remainder='passthrough')
```